# following a tutorial but when i try to validate it brings me this error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class Element < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  validates :element_type, inclusion: { :in ['paragraph','image','video-embed']}
end

def edit
  @paragraph = @post.elements.build(element_type: 'paragraph')
end
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: SyntaxError (C:/Users/Catherine/ngong-municipality/app/models/element.rb:3:ax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>
...agraph','image','video-embed']}
...                              ^
):

app/models/element.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>
app/models/element.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>
app/models/element.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>
app/controllers/authors/posts_controller.rb:18:in `edit'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `:` after `in` (`in:`) to indicate it is a symbol key.

```rb
class Element < ApplicationRecord
  validates :element_type, inclusion: { in: ['paragraph','image','video-embed'] }
end
```